# PHP Dropdown mySQL two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Edited version with working code:

Table schema:

category (catid, catname)

product (productid, catid, productname)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])); {

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
//get the id
$productid = (int) $_GET['id'];
} else {
    echo 'error'; }

$sql = $link->prepare("SELECT p.productid, p.catid pid, p.productname, c.catid cid, c.catname FROM product p
JOIN category c
WHERE p.productid = $productid");
$sql-> execute();
$result = $sql-> fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $option = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $pid = $row['pid'];
    $productname = $row['productname'];
    $catid = $row['cid'];
    $catname = $row['catname'];
    $option .= '<option name="'.$catname.'" value="'.$catid.'" '.($pid==$catid ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$catname.'</option>'."\r\n";
}
```

then in page:

```
<select name="xxx">
<? echo $option ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error while running this code?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what is not working? Also, you don't need the carriage return line feeds ("\r\n").

Comment: What happens when you run that query manually?

Comment: I'm not an SQL expert, but you may have to change `FROM category c` to `FROM category AS c`, and `product p` to `product AS p`.

Also, sanitize your input data or face the consequences!

Comment: If I run it manually in phpmyadmin it returns, 1 row, SELECT c.catid, c.catname, p.catid
FROM category c
JOIN product p ON c.catid = p.catid
WHERE p.productid=1

Comment: here you write wrong logic  `($catid==$catid )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach loop you are executing only a query not iterating the result set data. If it is not, then please explain your query() method.

Comment: Yea helps to have extra eyes I see what happened now. edited my original post to show working code